# How to verify client for internal apps

Tags: oauth-2.0

If I am developing a mobile app for public use - which means an internal app of company, server is not supposed to be used by third party apps.

***should i need to just have client _id passed by the mobile app to server to verify it's a valid client? or should I need to have the client secret passed too?***

*Should I have to use any encryption for this purpose?*

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/
This says not to use client secret for internal apps

So for every request that I make with mobile app, should I be passing the client id?

Answer (score 0):

A mobile app (or any kind of native app) cannot be a confidential client, meaning it cannot keep the client secret secret, because everyone who installs the app can (in theory) extract it from the code. Hence, using a client secret is pointless.

However, you can (and should) restrict your authorization server to redirect only to the (hard-coded) registered redirection endpoint URL of your app. This, in combination with [App claimed URLs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) can be used to make sure only your app can use the redirection endpoint. The endpoint URL should use HTTPS, so the identity of the server is verified.

An organization could still make a third-party app, create a DNS entry in their local network for your domain name and use certificate pinning, but this would be rather difficult and not viable outside of a local network.

Comment: So in theory, that harcoded end point in the app can also be seen right by decompiling

Comment: The endpoint URL or client ID are not secret, and they don't need to be.

Comment: "Android App Links use HTTP URLs that link to a website domain you own, so no other app can use your links" - https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html ... This (and the fact that you own the domain) prevents other apps from using the same redirection endpoint URL, and your authorization server prevents use of any other redirection endpoint URLs. Not sure how to do this on iOS, Windows Phone, etc.